# Functional testing of a RESTful POST in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rest, post

I'd like to write a functional test of a RESTful web service I'm working on in a Ruby on Rails app.

The test is of a POST request where the body of the request is a plain XML doc and not a form. Any pointers on how to do this? The problem I'm encountering is how to specify the body XML in the call to the post method.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me:

```
@request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = MY_XML_STRING
post :create
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do it by setting `@request.env['RAW_POST_BODY']` to the desired input stream.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution at http://de.softuses.com/6051

```rb
message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>content</tag>'

@xml_request_headers ||= {}
@xml_request_headers['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = @xml_request_headers['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/xml'

post '/controller/action.xml', message, @xml_request_headers
```

I actually defined `@xml_request_headers` in my `setup` method and can use it in all my tests in this file. Perhaps it would be a good idea to put it to `test_helper.rb` if it is required by more files.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [shoulda](http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/tree/master)'s "should_be_restful" macro. This macro will soon be [deprecated](http://thoughtbot.lighthouseapp.com/projects/5807/tickets/78-deprecate-should_be_restful) from shoulda and only available in the in [woulda](http://github.com/seanhussey/woulda/tree/master) gem.

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote a test script using Net:HTTP to test the REST service.