# how do I pass XML file as paremeter in Integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, functional-testing

I am writing integration test in rails, for that I have to pass XML file as parameter, I tried the below way

```
 test "integration" do
    @controller = ApiController.new
    file = "xxx/yyy.xml"
    post "register_user",file
    assert_true "something", @response.body
 end
```

but it shows as below error,

**NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "/xxx/yyy.xml":String**

Any one please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass xml like this:

```
test "integration" do
    @controller = ApiController.new
    entry = <<-EOF
      <atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
          xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
      </atom:entry>
    EOF

    url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi')
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(register_user, entry)
 end
```

Comment: Sam, now also i got the same error, "NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0xb5b80528>"

Comment: now it says, "NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: See my answer at [another question here on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336452/functional-testing-of-a-restful-post-in-ruby-on-rails/13365559#13365559)